# Left-align image and centered text on same level inside of a div?

Tags: html, css, image

```
HTML:
<br />
    <div class="UpperTitle">
        <img src="Images/CableSolve Logo.jpg" align="absmiddle" padding-right: 10px;" /> CableSolve Web Dashboard - Version 0.1.1
    </div>
<br />

CSS:
.UpperTitle
{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: #CEDEF4;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #224499;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

I have this setup currently. I would like to position the banner on the same level as the text, but I would like to have the banner on the left-hand side of the screen with the text in the center of the screen.

It seems like my only options are either: floating the image (would need a ton of hard-coded values to make this look OK), wrapping the text in a `<div>` to center it *specifically* (which causes it to drop below the image), or centering both the image and the text -- which is what I do currently.

I found a lot of various guides on this, but they seem to either float the image using a simple website layout, or vertically align the text, or find the center banner/text combo acceptable.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just exploit CSS position? like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/linmic/5L5V9/).

Cheers

Comment: I liked this one. :) Nice, simple and I understood exactly what was going on. Thanks! Nothing against Snippet's answer, I'm sure they both work relatively identically.

Answer (score 0):

put the text in a div and add:

```
height: /*height of parent*/
line-height:  /*height of parent*/
```