# Image to the left, text centered and keeping both in center of div when text changes?

Tags: css

I had this question answered here: [Left-align image and centered text on same level inside of a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572095/left-align-image-and-centered-text-on-same-level-inside-of-a-div)

I encountered an issue with this solution, however. The title has a series of font families defined. When one of the font families is not present on a user's computer, so a different font is shown, the static positioning of the image to its left becomes incorrect.

Is there a way to detect this occurring and add static positions for each font family? Or, even better, a way to just automatically keep the image in the right spot regardless of fon't size/family?

Thanks

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/linmic/5L5V9/

It inherits font-family from master page code.

Comment: Really don't think there's any way the presence or absence of a font on a users' computer would affect the positioning of another element. 99% likelihood something else is amiss. Link to your page or a jsfiddle. Could it be that you're discussing static positioning, which is actually the opposite of the absolute positioning that was prescribed for the image in that older question you linked?

Comment: Oh, I apologize. I did not realize static was a keyword in css. I am indeed using absolute positioning, the fiddle is the same as in the last post. I can edit it in here. The size of the font is controlling how big the colored area is -- larger fonts cause the overall colored area to increase which causes the image to be viewed as off-center.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean. Well, it's off center (assuming you mean vertically) when the box size changes because you didn't position it from the center :)  If you want it to always stay centered, position it as top: 50%, margin-top: -[half the image height]px;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an illustration of what I think you want, using top: 50%; image size of 48px, and top margin of  -24px to keep it vertically centered:

http://jsfiddle.net/5L5V9/5/

Comment: Is there a way to make the "top: 50%" start inside of the div? This place the image in the middle of my page + (1/2 height), unless I am doing something incorrect.

Comment: set relative on the object you want the the absolute element to be positioned based on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145903/position-overlay-div/6146021#6146021

Comment: Yeah, the original fiddle example posted in the question just had "relative" misspelled "rela1tive".

Answer (score 0):

The best way to *ensure* you get the font you want & the proper positioning of your image & title is to choose a font that is (legally) able to be used by @font-face.

For instructions & lots of @font-face fonts have a look at [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/)

Answer (score 0):

personally i like to use css background image for centering images next to text. here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mattimus/ZsmCG/

the downfall of this method is that you can't make the image clickable.